# Using robots.txt to block /?param=X

Tags: wordpress, search-engine, robots.txt

I have created a website using wordpress, and the first day it was full of dummy content until I uploaded mine. Google indexed pages such as:

www.url.com/?cat=1

Now these pages doesn't exists, and to make a removal request google ask me to block them on robots.txt

Should I use:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /?cat=
```

or

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /?cat=*
```

My robots.txt file would look something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-register.php
Disallow: /author
Disallow: /?cat=
Sitemap: http://url.com/sitemap.xml.gz
```

Does this look fine or can it cause any problem with search engines? Should I use Allow: / along with all the Disallow:?

Comment: There is no need to use an Allow here unless there are certain categories you want to allow.  For example, you're disallowing everything that starts with `/?cat=`.  But you might want to allow a specific category, as in `Allow: /?cat=something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with this actually

> To block access to all URLs that
>   include a question mark (?) (more
>   specifically, any URL that begins with
>   your domain name, followed by any
>   string, followed by a question mark,
>   followed by any string):

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*?
```

So I would actually go with:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*?cat=
```

[Resourse (Under patttern matching)](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should *not* use the robots.txt directives to handle removed content. If a search engine can't crawl it, it can't tell whether or not it's been removed and may continue to index (or even start indexing) those URLs. The right solution is to make sure that your site returns a 404 (or 410) HTTP result code for those URLs, then they'll drop out automatically over time.

If you want to use Google's urgent [URL removal tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals), you would have to submit these URLs individually anyway, so you would not gain anything by using a robots.txt disallow.

Answer (score 0):

If a search engine can't crawl it, it can't tell whether or not it's been removed and may continue to index (or even start indexing) those URLs.